# Sincronización GIT - LARAVEL - HOST

Tags: laravel, git, ftp, gitlab

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un projecto php usando el framework Laravel, uso git para el control de versiones; programo en local, actualizo el repositorio para salvar el projecto y luego manualmente subo el projecto.

Sé que se puede sincronizar el repositorio y el servidor para que se actualice automáticamente mediante CI/CD, el detalle es que en el servidor la estructura de mi projecto cambia. En public_html tengo el contenido de la carpeta public de mi porjecto, en la raiz del server tengo una carpeta con el resto del contenido, esto por serguridad.

Mi pregenta es si puedo sincronizar el repositorio para que actualice el projecto en diferentes carpetas de mi servidor.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes hacer eso, pero si que puedes hacer que la public de laravel sea public_html.

Tienes que registrar la nueva ruta publica dado que ya no es public sino public_html

`\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

```
    /**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5

Comment: Sí, ese archivo es parte de una serie de rutas que se deben cambiar para que reconozca la carpeta public en public_html, con eso no tengo problema. Mi duda es si puedo actualizar el codigo que está en el servidor al hacer pull a mi repositorio, aun cuando tengo segmentado el proyecto en carpetas diferente en el servidor.

Comment: Lo que estas intentando hacer ni es posible ni es lógico. Lo que tienes que hacer es poner el proyecto entero y cambiar solo  el nombre de la public como te explico. Si lo que te preocupa es que accedan a los controladores, lo que estas haciendo no es la solución.